# Как проверить, что патч подойдет к исходникам обновленного ядра?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal, lan

После очередного обновления системы перестала работать сетевая карта. Получил патч для ядра.
Как проверить, что патч подойдет к исходникам обновленного ядра.

Какой командой проверить наложится ли патч на исходники:

```
patch --dry-run
patch --applicable
patch --unified
patch -pl
patch --context
```

Comment: pinguem.ru пытаетесь пройти с помощью stackoverflow? :)

Comment: да, а что такого. Вопросы ведь можно задавать

Comment: не-не, ничего, удачи пожелать хотел 8D

Comment: `man patch` не пробовали ?

Comment: *Какой командой проверить наложится ли патч на исходники* — ни одной из перечисленных.

Comment: в онлайн консолях его нету, но я думаю первый вапинат

Comment: `man patch` можно набирать не в консоли, а в гугле, он отлично понимает. и в принципе вы правильно думаете, первый более похож, но ключей все равно маловато. А вообще такими вопросами вы подставляете и себя и потенциального отвечающего. Я помню сколько минусов наловил за ответ на вопрос из теста с другого сайта (я же не знал, что он из тестов, а те кто знали минусовали и вопрос и ответ ...)

Comment: Ну тогда 1 и 4?

Answer (score 0):

Параметр -p важен при указании  "глубины" расположения пачей относительно исходов. Так что, скорее всего, надо задать

```
patch -p1 --dry-run
```